# $\Delta+1$ coloring using O($\Delta*\log^*n$) algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

I have homework related to coloring/local algorithms:

If $\Delta$ is a max degree find a  $O_\Delta(\log^*n)$ local algorithm for $\Delta+1$ coloring,

To be honest, I am not sure what $O_\Delta(\log^*n)$  means, could you please give me some examples or hints to solve this exercise?

EDIT: I found it means $O(c(\Delta)\cdot\log^*n)$ but I am still struggling to understand an algorithm like this.

Comment: For regular graphs, edge coloring is same as finding edge disjoint maximal matching problem. You can use augmentation path idea in matching to find it (See matching section in diestel). Though i havent calculated its complexity.

Comment: Thank you and yes we also did some maximal matching but i wasn't sure how to connect thank you

Answer (score 4):

I believe that what you are looking for are the algorithms "Color-Constant-Degree-Graph" and "6-Color-Rooted-Tree" in [this paper.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/194591743.pdf)

The 6 coloring algorithm uses a local algorithm to color the nodes of a graph by having nodes process their color based on their neighbors colors, synchronously.

It does this in $O(log^*n)$ time. In case you weren't familiar with $log^*n$, it's the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm), which is the number of times the logarithm must be applied to get down to 2.

The Constant Degree Graph algorithm also performs in $O(log^*n)$ time, but also uses $(\triangle+1)$ colors.

[This paper](https://disco.ethz.ch/courses/podc_allstars/lecture/chapter1.pdf) is a little bit more gentle in explaining how the algorithms work, and [these slides](https://jukkasuomela.fi/dda-2010/lecture-2.pdf) demonstrate a few iterations of one of the algorithms.